# Where is catalina_base and catalina_home located for tomcat6?

Tags: tomcat6, tomcat

I recently installed tomcat6 with apt-get and have got it up and running. Ubuntu doesnt set the $CATALINA_BASE and $CATALINA_HOME environment variables during the install. How can I locate these directories, so I can manually set them?

Comment: tomcat7: http://askubuntu.com/questions/368472/tomcat7s-catalina-home-in-debian-ubuntu

Comment: Similar: https://askubuntu.com/q/46757/256002

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Both are stored and can be set in `/etc/default/tomcat6`. By default, CATALINA_HOME is `/usr/share/tomcat6`, and CATALINA_BASE is `/var/lib/tomcat6`.

Answer (score 3):

In either Tomcat6 or Tomcat7 installed with Apt-Get, find the declarations of 
CATALINA_HOME and CATALINA_BASE, in /etc/init.d/tomcat6 or tomcat7, and EXPORT them to the OS variables. They are then visible on a ENV command. and for use by other software.

Answer (score 1):

I have ubuntu v10. 
And I have tomcat v6 installed at which is at /usr/lib/tomcat6/...

Answer:
In my system, both variables are stored in /etc/init.d/tomcat6