# tomcat7's CATALINA_HOME in Debian/Ubuntu

Tags: configuration, tomcat7

Where is tomcat7's CATALINA_HOME in Debian/Ubuntu, and more importantly **how did you find it**?

I'm OK with Debian rearranging default software installations, but we must be able to find out where basic resources have been moved. Is there any easy-to-find README or config file in the tomcat7 installation that has this vital info?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is under `/usr/share/tomcat7/`.

One way to find the location is to look into the service startup script `/etc/init.d/tomcat7`. You will find these lines in it:

```
NAME=tomcat7
...
CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/$NAME
```

---

Edit:

In Ubuntu 20/Tomcat 9, it is under `/usr/share/tomcat9/`.

You can find the location in the systemd service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/tomcat9.service`:

```
Environment="CATALINA_HOME=/usr/share/tomcat9"
```

Comment: As of Ubuntu 20.04/Tomcat 9, there is no `/etc/init.d/tomcatX`.  If anyone has an updated answer to this question, it would be helpful.

Comment: @BoreaDeitz See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.4 with tomcat7.
Apparently, default CATALINA_HOME is now pointing to /var/lib/tomcat7/conf